# Play stereo sound in java?

Tags: java, audio, frequency, stereo-3d

Is there any way, without having to download additional API's or libraries to play a different sound in each ear?

For example, generating two tones directly with byte[] arrays and playing it with something like a `SourceDataLine` to play the two tones, one in each ear, simultaneously?

And if there is no way to do it without external Libraries, would you be able to tell me which I need, and how to use them? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create two player objects (or two ouput streams) and pan each to the preferred side.

Comment: How would I pan audio?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of of using Java MediaPlayer: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html.  Then set use `.setBalance(-1.0)` for the left channel and `.setBalance(1.0)` for the right channel.

Comment: Doesn't MediaPlayer require reading a file? Or is there a way to just play a byte array directly?

Comment: Since it can use files, you can pass data through a fileinputstream